# How to add EXTRA_REFERRER to CustomTabsIntent builder in Chrome custom tab for Android

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

I am using newly launched Chrome Custom tabs for android instead of using webviews. [This is the link to their documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs)

Here is the code that shows how to use it.

```
String url = ¨https://paul.kinlan.me/¨;
CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
```

Question is that I want to add Intent.EXTRA_REFERRER to this. below is the para copied from their blog in their own words..

> It's usually very important for websites to track where their traffic
>   is coming from. Make sure you let them know you are sending them users
>   by setting the referrer when launching your Custom Tab

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_REFERRER, 
             Uri.parse(Intent.URI_ANDROID_APP_SCHEME + "//" + context.getPackageName()));
```

I failed to figure out any intent created to launch custom tabs.. Where to add this line?? If somebody has came across this, help please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can put the extra on the Intent that is inside the CustomTabsIntent created by the builder like the following:

```
String url = ¨https://paul.kinlan.me/¨;
CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
customTabsIntent.intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_REFERRER,
        Uri.parse("android-app://" + context.getPackageName()));
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
```

**Explanation:** Under the hood, a Custom tab is opened by using regular a [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) with a set of Extras that configure the UI customization. It's possible to see more on how it works at the [Low Level API section](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs#LOW_LEVEL_API) of the docs. When `CustomTabsIntent.Builder#build()` is called, it creates a CustomTabsIntent, with a properly configured Intent inside it. This intent is still exposed by the API and that's what we use to add the [EXTRA_REFERRER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_REFERRER).

Comment: Yes, I changed my code. but can you brief me what it is??

Comment: Added a short explanation.

Comment: I think the documentation is wrong, because Intent.URI_ANDROID_APP_SCHEME is an integer flag that has the value 2 which makes the referrer URI "2://com.example.app".
So I think it would be better for set EXTRA_REFERRER to Uri.parse("android-app://" + context.getPacakgeName()

Comment: Adding EXTRA_REFERRER doesn't seem to be working anymore. Launching https://www.whatismyreferer.com/ for example doesn't show it.